# Lua is throwing error when Vim keymap includes "\"

Tags: lua, neovim

I am recently migrating from vimscript to lua with Nvim. While converting the keymappings, I ran into a problem with the following keymap:

[ init.vim ]

```
tmap <leader>e <C-\><C-n>
```

[ init.lua ] ( error )

```
map('t','<leader>e','<C-\><C-n>')
```

Whenever I reload with above keymap, Nvim will throw the following error:

[image]

I'm assuming that "\" might be the problem. If so, how do I refactor the keymap properly for it to work? Any feedback will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is most likely as the `\` is used to escape special characters in the string. Try putting

```
map('t','<leader>e','<C-\\><C-n>')
```

This way you are telling Lua that you want the backslash character and not some other special character.